# how to make ng-repeat work with filter and one time binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, frontend

Good day.
I am looking a way to speed up 
items rendering with ng-repeat.
My angular version is 1.6.4
My code example, responsible for templates rendering, is:

```
div ng-repeat="data in vm.items
 | filter: {status: vm.filterValue, title: vm.fitler@Value} 
 |  orderBy:vm.sortParam"
```

I used for this purpose one time binding

```
<div ng-repeat="data in ::vm.items 
| filter: {status: vm.filterValue, title: vm.fitler@Value} 
|  orderBy:vm.sortParam"
```

it renders the data on the page, but filter is not working at all.
Each repeated  element has it's separate directive with controller, scope and listeners (i've also added :: inside {{}} for optimization aims).

Also i've added debounce(250) parameter for input, used for search. It makes UI bit better (smaller freezing between input some text and it's appearing in input)

Can you, please, provide recommendations to increase performance of rendering with ng-repeat and how to use filter with ng-repeat and filter option?

Comment: Can't be sure at the moment, but I think bind once doesn't filter because it applies the filter after the binding. Try filtering before rendering the view, in the resolve of the route or something.

Comment: but i need to filter in real time. there are the list of items with name property and i use input for search by this property after data to be rendered. in this case no effect to use filter before data rendering

Comment: If the data changes, I don't think bind once makes much sense, but it goes beyond my knowledge, sorry.

Comment: do not use bind once, use track by

Comment: If would make more sense to perform the filtering in the controller then use the ng-repeat on the newly altered vm.items

Comment: i use track by item.id in all ng-repeat loops

Comment: how to perform real time filtering without |filter directive and will it give some performance profit?

Comment: As @rrd suggested - do the filtering in the controller and after this you can try adding the items to the repeated collection by chunks. `::` when used with `ngRepeat` in best case will remove one extra `$$watcher` and is suggested to be used when the collection is not going to change over time.